# Produce a Deduplicated list out of a free text email field in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

My Problem:

I have a table field with email addresses hand entered into it for a given data row.  I want to pull the data from that field, deduplicate the addresses and produce one string to use as a recipient list for an email.

A select of some rows looks like this:

```
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, KEVIN@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, IRON.MIKE@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, BUG@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, SANDI@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,KEVIN@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,MALIK@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,MALIK@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,SANDI@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,KEVIN@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,SANDI@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,MALIK@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
EVENTS@PHONY_EMAIL.COM 
KEVIN@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,IRON.MIKE@PHONY_EMAIL.COM,BUG@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ABIGAIL@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, KEVIN@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, IRON.MIKE@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, BUG@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, SANDI@PHONY_EMAIL.COM, MALIK@PHONY_EMAIL.COM
```

I think my query needs a little tweak, as currently it only builds the string for the first value in each row.

```
SELECT Listagg(Split_List
,', ') Within GROUP(ORDER BY Split_List) "Email Addresses"
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT (Regexp_Substr(Jp.Lgr_Notify_Email
,'[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'
,1)) Split_List
FROM   J_Post Jp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your string to few rows, sorry can't write code from phone.
Please find example of code in this article. You should use thrid example.
http://sprogram.com.ua/en/articles/oracle-select-from-string-varchar2